# Better syntax for a return statement in a method which retrieves a query String

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, query-string

I use this simple method to retrieve a Query String from a Page a returning a `Int`. In case a valid Id can not be found I would like return a default value `int 0`.

I would like to know if there is a better way to write this method, in details:

- Would be better use just a single return statement instead the two? If yes what is the best way to do it?
- Shall I perform any other checking when retrieving the Query String?

```cs
protected int GetPageIndex()
{
    int output;
    bool result = Int32.TryParse(Request.QueryString["page"], out output);
    if(result)
        return output;
    return output = 0; // Return Default value
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just initialize it before you try to parse it... Anyways, Int32.TryParse sets the value to 0 if the conversion is unsuccessful... :) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx

```
protected int GetPageIndex()
    {
        int output = 0;
        Int32.TryParse(Request.QueryString["page"], out output);
        return output;
    }
```

Comment: It is not necessary to initialize with `0`, as `TryParse` ignores any input value an sets to `0` anyway if conversion fails. If you initialize with another value (`int output = 1`), it will still have value of `0` after failed conversion. So Initializing it at all might be confusing.

Answer (score 3):

You're safe to simply return `output`, since you're seemingly not concerned as to whether `TryParse` succeeded or not, and by assigning a value of `0` to `output` initially, for clarity, then that is what will be returned if `TryParse` fails anyway.

```
protected int GetPageIndex()
{
    int output = 0;
    int.TryParse(Request.QueryString["page"], out output);
    return output;
}
```

Comment: The exact same reply... Beat you with a minute... ;)

Comment: Time does take its toll, but I've never been beaten _with_ a unit of time before - that would be the ultimate comeuppance for man by its nemesis. ;)

Comment: It is not necessary to initialize with `0`, as `TryParse` ignores any input value an sets to `0` anyway if conversion fails. If you initialize with another value (`int output = 1`), it will still have value of `0` after failed conversion. So Initializing it at all might be confusing.

Comment: @awe Please take the time to read my explanation that comes prior to the code snippet (re _for clarity_; if your views on clarity in this matter differ then so be it, but for me _this_ is clearer since the zero-value is visualised and naturally expected.)

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment: I did read your explanation, and I disagree that this is necessarily clarifying. If I didn't know that `TryParse` actually set the value to `0`, I would think that when I see the output beeing initialized, it means that it is actually effective as default value (which is not, because initiliazing to `1` would have no effect).

Comment: @awe Then in that case I would worry that there is a bigger issue here: that someone doesn't know the innards of `out`, and that it _must_ be set prior to leaving scope - all we're doing is aligning with the default.

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment: I am not a native English speaker, I have probably expressed myself faulty. What would be the correct way to say that I beat you to it, and I answered a minute before you? (just be careful, or I'll come beating you with a full hour next time ;))

Comment: @Erik: I knew exactly what you meant, I was just kidding. To say "beat me _by_ a minute would do the job, though. :)

Comment: Of course, "by" was the correct preposition to use... Thanks. In Norwegian, we use "med", which means "with". I think maybe prepositions are the most difficult parts of foreign languages... I almost always get them wrong in French... ;) Thanks for the language lesson. :)

Answer (score 1):

How about this to use less code, with regards to checking the query string I dont think you need to check for null as the try parse should handle the null value.

```
protected int GetPageIndex()
{
    int output;
    return Int32.TryParse( Request.QueryString[ "page" ], out output ) ? output : 0;
}
```

Comment: This is certainly the simplest form, and also allows for default value other than `0`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with

```
protected int GetPageIndex()
{
    int output = 0;
    Int32.TryParse(Request.QueryString["page"], out output);
    return output; 
}
```

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment - you're right, result is redundant, jsut leftover from original code. Edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
int output;
return Int32.TryParse(Request.QueryString["page"], out output) ? output : 0;
```

Comment: @GibboK It's hard to understand this downvote. Yes, the code is not perfect, you can simply return the output variable, but using such a construction it's easier to understand the code.